# Bank statements for Schengen & UK visa applications

Tags: visas, schengen, uk

I am hoping to travel to Europe in August 2017 for a month. My itinerary is to arrive in London, travel to France, Switzerland, Italy and Greece and go back to London form my return flight to Melbourne. I am a permanent resident of Australia for the last 4 years.

I have been saving for my Europe trip since last year. I created another savings account with my bank and transferred money to that for the European trip. I have around 12,000 AUD in that account. Is that sufficient for me as proof of funds to obtain Schenagen and UK visas?

My everyday savings account would have usually 1500 AUD after my expenditures and transferring money to my Europe savings account. Is it okay if I provide 3 or 6 months of bank statements of that specific savings account? Do they require my everyday savings account into which my salary is deposited, as well? Do they require credit card statements, too?

My partner is travelling with me and he is a citizen of Australia, so he doesn't need to obtain visas. We are hoping to pay the hotel bookings and flights (prior to obtaining my visas) from his account/credit card so that I still maintain 12K balance in my account at the time I apply for my visas.

Would that be a problem? Would they need to see from my bank statements the payments I have made for flights and hotels?

Comment: You ask a lot of questions which will all be covered by Gayot Fow's [excellent piece on provenance of funds](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105).

The only question perhaps not covered in his piece is credit card statements. My understanding is UK consular officers typically don't care much for credit cards and credit card statements because those funds sometimes can become unavailable when in a foreign country because the card can be closed by the issuing bank. The prefer real INCOME.

Comment: Hi 
Thank you for your advise and I read that topic which is useful.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation about funds is used as proof of:

- That you can maintain yourself during the visit (12,000 AUD are 8,664 €, definitely way more than enough to sustain yourself for a month, even if you had to paid hotels and air tickets from it).
- That these funds are yours (they come from your salary/other incomes, instead of being money someone lends you to "sponsor" your visa)
- That you have ties to your country of origin (for example a job) that will ensure that you are not enticed to stay in the Schengen area beyond the limits of the visa.

In addition to bank statements, your work contract in Australia and a couple of pay slips would help the IO to dismiss any doubts he could have about the above points. Explaining that you are travelling with your boyfriend and including the same documentation from him will not hurt, even if it is not required.

Comment: Thank you for your advise.ill be able to provide payslips and letter from my employer confirming my job.Along with that if I only provide the savings accounts   statements which I made for europe travel purpose is ok? Or do they need to see my everyday savings account statement which has my salary deposit and other expenses ? ( most my expenses are in credit card though)  . Also around three months ago i transferred 5K to someone and he will be paying that back to me fairly soon.therefore in te bank statement when there is 5K appearing sudden would they not accept it?

Comment: In case your money is returned in the statement period you need to bring, also bring the statements for the period before, upto and in including those that hold the period when you transferred that money to them.